# Postgresql How to define sum case when where statement returns 0 results

Tags: sql, postgresql

The following SQL produces the right result when both tables `t1` and `t2` have a record with the same value in field `a`

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, sum(case when t2.d > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as d
FROM t1, t2 
WHERE t1.e = '123' AND t1.a=t2.a
GROUP BY t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
ORDER BY a ASC;
```

When `t2` has no `a` records that  match `t1`, I wish to return `t1` values and have d set to 0.

**Is this possible** in one SQL or it must be two different ones?

Example: if these are the values in DB

```
t1                                        t2
a   |  b   |  c                           a  |  d 
1   |  11  |  111                         1  |  0 
2   |  22  |  222                         1  |  2 
3   |  33  |  333                         2  |  0 
4   |  44  |  444                         2  |  1
                                          3  |  1
                                          3  |  4
                                          3  |  7
```

The result of the above sql is:

```
a   |  b   |  c    |  d
1   |  11  |  111  |  1
2   |  22  |  222  |  1
3   |  33  |  333  |  3
```

And the result I wish to receive is:

```
a   |  b   |  c    |  d
1   |  11  |  111  |  1
2   |  22  |  222  |  1
3   |  33  |  333  |  3
4   |  44  |  444  |  0
```

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

In your case, you want a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c,
       SUM(case when t2.d > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as d
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN
     t2 
     ON t1.a = t2.a
WHERE t1.e = '123' 
GROUP BY t1.a, t1.b, t1.c
ORDER BY a ASC;
```

Or use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select count(*)
        from t2
        where t2.a = t1.a and t2.d > 0
       ) as d
from t1
where t1.e = '123';
```

Comment: Can you elaborate why the use of comma is wrong/ bad?

Comment: Well the newer  join syntax (only 30 years old) is much  easier to see exactly what is happening, and you cannot completely miss a necessary join predicate (incomplete yes but not omitted entirely) which results in a Cartesian product (every row from the table missing the predicate joined with every row in every other table). In this case the solution requires an OUTER JOIN which (afaik) Postgres in incapable of doing with a comma separated table format.

Comment: You have fallen into the documentation trap that shows the old style. Updated in v14, check that [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-join.html).